# Using http-proxy to create reverse proxy in Meteor causes missing module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, proxy, http-proxy

**CONTEXT**

I want to load a third party website into an iframe, first passing it through a proxy in order to change its CORS policy to be able to modify its DOM. I'm using Meteor 1.3 with React and found this to be the most popular solution so far: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

**PROBLEM**

One of the requirements of http-proxy is 'http', which I've installed with `npm install http --save`. However, when I try to write the following:

```
//Create Proxy
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const http = require('http');

//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000'}).listen(8000); // See (†)

//
// Create your target server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

I get an error `Cannot find module .../node_modules/http`. Not sure why this might be happening, should I be using something other than `http`?

**EDIT 1:** There is an http folder inside my node_modules, but it just contains a `package.json` file. Also, the version of http installed is "0.0.0" according to my root folder's package.json.

Comment: That's strange. Did you checked your `node_modules` folder? Does it contain `http`?

Comment: Good point @Tdm - yes there is, I added more details to the initial question

Comment: I just tried to install both `http` and `http-proxy`. And in my case `http` contains 2 files: `package.json` and `.meteor-portable`. But `http` is required without any errors. Where is your `require('http')` code located (I mean path to file in project)?

Comment: In the server/methods/test.js  -> I'm using Meteor 1.3 with React and the Mantra framework.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with mantra too. I used this repo https://github.com/mantrajs/mantra-sample-blog-app. It works fine as well.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the `Cannot find module` error only occurs the first time after I've restarted the server and I trigger the event. On subsequent event triggers, I get a `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'createProxyServer'` - this seems to be addressed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/wYQ8RUkXPxA